# How to show a product on the frontpage? Which block to add?

Tags: magento

I am trying to implement a single product into the frontpage via the cms.

The code I use in the cms content is:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="2" template="catalog/product/view.phtml"}}
```

But nothing happens.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your template and paste the following :

```
    // lets say template name one_product.phtml
<?php
    $productId = $this->getProduct_id();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);  //load product                                                      
?>
<div class="product">
    <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" >
    <img class="product-img" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(100, 100); ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($product->getName()) ?>" />
    </a>
</div>
```

so CMS layout XML should be :

```
{{block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="10" template="catalog/product/one_product.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thx!
I created the templatefile and added the block via the cms layout xml updater, but i get an error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php on line 55`
Here is the line 55:
`$title = $product->getMetaTitle();`

Comment: into xml cms update `<reference name="content">
      <block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="1" template="catalog/product/one_product.phtml" />
</reference>` and created one_product.phtml into my theme-template-folder

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but a good solution is

Under Configuration Web Default Pages, set the Default Web URL to catalog/product/view/id/2